# Linearize tricky constraint to MILP, LP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, linearization, cvx

It's hard to describe this constraints. Please check this:

It is a selection problem.

| Item Name | Brand | Value | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item 1 | A | 0.1 | 0.2 |
| item 2 | B | 0.2 | 0.3 |
| item 3 | A | 0.1 | 0.3 |

We want to select several items from 1000 items satisfying this constraint:

*The proportion of items with **weighted price** between 0.1 and 0.2 in the final selected combination is less than 50%*.

**weighted price** is a little bit tricky concept:

*The weighted price of an item = brand weighted price of all items under the brand of the item in the final selected combination*

*brand weighted price = sum(price) / sum(value)*

> eg. If we select item 1, item 2 and item 3 in the final combination:
>
> weighted price of item 1 / item 3 = sum(price)/sum(value) = (0.2+0.3)/(0.1+0.1)
>
> weighted price of item 2 = sum(price)/sum(value) = 0.3/0.2

I am using MILP solver (**CBC, CPLEX**). I want to know how to linearize this problem, or whether this attempt is possible. Thanks so much.

---

Update:

I'd like to provide an detailed example to help specify this problem:

Now we have 10 different items

| **Item Name** | **Brand** | **Value** | **Price** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **item 1** | A | 0.1 | 0.2 |
| item 2 | B | 0.2 | 0.3 |
| **item 3** | A | 0.1 | 0.3 |
| item 4 | A | 0.2 | 0.3 |
| **item 5** | A | 0.3 | 0.5 |
| item 6 | B | 0.1 | 0.2 |
| **item 7** | B | 0.2 | 0.3 |
| item 8 | A | 0.3 | 0.6 |
| **item 9** | B | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| **item 10** | B | 0.2 | 0.2 |

Constraint: (**num** of selected items with **weighted price** between **1.0 and 1.5**) / (**num** of selected items) <= 50%

Assume item 1,3,5,7,9,10 are selected.

for item 1,3,5 (Brand A) **weighted price** = sum(price)/sum(value) = (0.2+0.3+0.5) / (0.1+0.1+0.3) = 2

for item 7,9,10 (Brand B) **weighted price** = sum(price)/sum(value) = (0.3+0.3+0.2) / (0.2+0.3+0.2) = 1.33

Thus there are **3** selected items whose weighted prices are between 1.0 and 1.5.

Constraint:

(**num** of selected items with **weighted price** between **1.0 and 1.5**) / (**num** of selected items) =3/6=50%<=50%

Constraint is satisfied.

As you can see the most tricky part is that **weighted price of each item changes with the final combination**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updated, add a specific case

Answer (score 1):

So if $x_{i}$ be binary variable, B is set of brands indexed over over $ I =\{1,2,...1000 \}$ and a combination set IB$=\{(1,A),(2,B),...\} $, $p$ as price and $v$ as value  with $x=1$ if object $i$ is selected, then
$ M(y_{1,i}-1)+ 0.1\sum_{i\in IB:b=B_i} v_ix_{i} \le \sum_{i\in IB:b=B_i} p_ix_{i} \le 0.2\sum_{i\in IB:b=B_i} v_ix_i + M(1-y_{1,i})$

$M(y_{2,i}-1)+\sum_{i\in IB:b=B_i} p_ix_{i}\le 0.1\sum_{i\in IB:b=B_i} v_ix_{i} + M(1-y_{2,i})$

$M(y_{3,i}-1)+ 0.2\sum_{i\in IB:b=B_i} v_ix_i \le \sum_{i\in IB:b=B_i} p_ix_i\le+ M(1-y_{3,i})\ \ \forall i\in I$

$\sum_{j=1}^3 y_{j,i}=x_i\ \ \forall i\in I$

The above 3 constraints for all $i$ evaluates the weighted brand value using binary $y_{j,i}$ where $y_{1,i}=1$ if weighted value is $[0.1,0.2] $ for selected $i$.

If $N$ is predetermined number to be selected then
$ \sum_i x_i = N$
$ \sum_i y_{1,i} \le {N\over 2}$
or
$ 2\sum_i y_{1,i} \le \sum_i x_i$